# How to resolve dependencies inside of Startup.cs in .NET 6?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

We need to get an instance of a service inside of the `Configure()` method in `Startup.cs` for an Azure Function app on .NET 6. For .NET core apps, this can be achieved by adding the service inside the `ConfigureServices()` method, and then getting the required service in the `Configure()`.

However, in a .NET function app, there isn't a separation between `Configure()` and `ConfigureServices()` - there's only one method, `Configure()`.

How do we both register and then get an instance of a service in this method? If we try:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
    var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var clientFactory = provider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
}
```

Then, using `clientFactory` anywhere throws an error `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`. Is there a way to "wait" for all services to be built, then get an instance of it?

Note: We are specifically looking for a way to do this in .NET functions. All the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786653/resolve-dependencies-inside-startup-cs) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774559/how-do-i-get-a-instance-of-a-service-in-asp-net-core-3-1) currently are for .NET core.

Comment: Please refer [Register Services in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT But how do I get an instance of the service that was registered? Using `GetService` from `BuildServiceProvider` doesn't seem to work very well